# InApp Plan change always gives "Cannot connect to iTunes store" error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, itunes-store

I have implemented IAP in my app. It consist of 3 plans(monthly, semi annual, yearly) in 1 group and same level. Its working fine in sandbox for first time purchase. But if am trying to change the plan it will show the confirmation alerts then the transaction will fail with "**Cannot connect to iTunes store"** error(But in store that purchase will be in success mode. If we try it again then we will get the receipt).

Noticed so many questions on the same error but ma case is **plan switching**. Can anyone confirm it occurs in **only sandbox mode or not**?.

I have removed the real accounts from settings, restarted the test device, rechecked with multiple test accounts. Couldn't find the solution.

Comment: iTunes error codes are a mess... Assuming you have your IAPs [configured correctly](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard) since the are working the first time, that error is thrown when trying to purchase from a subscription group that is already active for that iTunes account. If you're getting the receipt and purchase is succeeding, how are you seeing that error? Can you post code?

Comment: @enc_life: Yh u are right error codes are really a mess. I have solved this issue with a workaround. I was trying to purchase from a subscription group that is already active then got the transaction failure with the error "cannot.." in app side. But in iTunes its in success(if we try to purchase again it will show the alert that the item is purchased).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have solved this case with a workaround. Even if we got the error or not the receipt will be available, try to validate the receipt. If the subscription plan changed it will get in receipt validation. Don't need to consider the **"buyProduct"** failed state. No need to display the error just we can try receipt validation if that also failed then the purchase is not done actually.